# Multiple Line Label in AChartEngine based BarChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm writing an application for Android which contains Bar Charts, The Bar Chart is built by using the AChartEngine API. The X axis label is quite long and overlaps the other labels, I was wondering if it is possible to have a line break in the label or have a multiple line label. I tried going through the API documentation but i found no answers and Google proves to be no better.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can break xlable directly but i tried to rotate the lables so that they fit the page

```
renderer.setXLabelsAngle(45f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a line break using getTimeChartView. By using \n in format parameter of getTimeChartView, but I am not sure how you can get the same with BarCharts.

```
mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer,"HH:mm \n dd-MM");
```

I am still looking for how to have multiple line labels.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a multiline label with custom text label.

```
renderer.ShowCustomTextGrid = true;
renderer.AddXTextLabel (0, "first line \n  second line");
```