# Achartengine line graph issue

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph

I am using achart library to display line graph in my android application.
I want to customize lable like wrapint up the label text so as to it uses min width on the geapn. the label has to be chopped out like jan 14, new line 2014 year shuould be on the new line below date . Please suggest me a good solution.

Comment: can you show some snap what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can set a minimum width for your label without changing core library but you can define a String field which consist of two parts then when you set your labels put a "\n" between them like :

```
multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(Bar_2007, Year + " \n " + Month);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698852/multiple-line-label-in-achartengine-based-barchart) will help. \n works well. I customized the library to achieve this, as i needed to show image label and text in 2 lines.